# Packaging polarity indication of a supercapacitor (polarity indicated by arrows)

Tags: polarity, supercapacitor

I obtained some supercaps from an auction site.
As is often the case for low cost components from such sources, these do not have supplied data and such branding as there is does not appear traceable.

I would like to know if there is a standard for polarity for such devices and how likely it is that generic devices such as this one follow the "standard".
My samples have an arrow on the label which may indicate polarity, but this is uncertain.

To make my query specific, but also liable to be generally useful, here is a set of closely related questions:

- What is the polarity of this supercapacitor (4F, 5.5V)?
- How was the polarity determined in this case?
- Is there a standard for polarity for such capacitors?
- What does the arrow indicates?

[image: image of two-cell stacked coin-like supercapacitor]

Some details of specific product [here](http://www.ebay.de/itm/5pcs-5-5V-4F-H-Type-Super-Farad-Capacitor-double-layer-capacitance-/291761451294?)

Including this diagram:

[image]

Comment: You have a great answer. Accept it. The lead on top in your picture is (-) and the lead we can barely see, on the bottom, is (+).

Comment: Their dimension description drawing contains the polarity

Comment: You should post this question to the eBay seller.  EE.SE isn't his volunteer technical support.

Comment: @PlasmaHH-I only see dimensions. Which picture are you referring to?

Comment: @SolarWind  I added a coy of the relevant product link which had been inappropriately deleted and the dimension image as I cannot post an answer. On the dimensioning image you can see very small polarity sumbols next to the leabs - "-" by the B text and "+" to the left of the P text.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon-Thanks. I magnified the image several times and indeed there seems to be a tiny + and - marking. Though the + sign could be anything else. At this magnification the image is too blurry. +1

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - I deleted the link after I got an answer from user2943160 because I don't want to lead other people to such poor product. The capacitor will self discharge from 5.00V to 4.90V in a few seconds, then continue to self discharge (a bit slower).

Comment: The "pinout" is as for a standard "H type" supercap. While there is no guarantee that every manufacturer will follow the "industry standard", the few examples I have found so far so do so. The following are from "Alibaba" and similar: 
[Better diagram here](https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1cn5mGXXXXXbbXVXXq6xXFXXXW/220230767/HTB1cn5mGXXXXXbbXVXXq6xXFXXXW.jpg), and [here](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/5-5V-0-33F-Coin-Super_60037791353.html) (scroll down), and [here](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Super-Capacitor-Type-Super-capacitor-5_1971964830.html)

Comment: @SolarWind  I edited your question so that it becomes more generically useful. The aim was to make the question of long term value for people seeking to design equipment using generic components readily available on auction sites. Hopefully the rewritten question is consistent with your original intentions but looks less like a 'shopping question'.  Feel free to re-edit as appropriate (Hey, it's your question :-) ). I've asked the moderators to reopen the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since the product you purchased has no background information, you can't be certain. However, the *convention* for these stacked-disk type capacitors is **polarity mark points to negative lead**. This is the same as is the convention with conventional electrolytic capacitors.

For example, the [Eaton KR-5R5V474-R](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/eaton/KR-5R5V474-R/283-2815-ND/1556243):

[image: Digkey image of the KR-5R5V474-R]

Has its [datasheet](http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/dam/public/bussmann/Electronics/Resources/product-datasheets/Bus_Elx_DS_4327_KR_Series.pdf) show:

[image: device drawing of the KR-5R5V474-R showing polarity indication]

Similarly, for the [Panasonic EEC-S0HD224H](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electronic-components/EEC-S0HD224H/P10788-ND/285584):

[image: Digikey image of the EEC-S0HD224H]

Has the same arrow convention considering the asymmetric leads with polarity indicated in its [datasheet](http://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/RDG0000/ABC0000C16.pdf):

[image: device drawing of the EEC-S0HD224H showing polarity indication]

Comment: I suppose that makes sense by analogy with CR2032 (etc.) cells where the smaller-diameter electrode is negative. But why do capacitor manufacturers make the labelling so cryptic? (Rhetorical.)

Comment: Why do capacitor manufacturers make the labeling so cryptic? (Actual non-rhetorical question) :)